# Fixing sticky keys without removing the keys?

Tags: keyboard, netbook, cleaning

we had an E-Machine netbook brought in today that has sticky keys. (don't ask me why we said we'd fix it) Well, I've looked at a few howtos for fixing it, but they all require removing the keys. When I tried to remove the keys, I got the key to like a 45 degree angle and it still didn't budge, so I'm pretty sure the keys are non-removable.

Is it common for places to even be able to find a replacement keyboard for netbooks and is there a way to fix sticky keys without removing the keys?

The model number is an `eMachine 250-1162`

Comment: heh, "sticky keys" is a windows term. But yes, you should be able buy replacements from eBay or similar. What's your make/model?

Comment: @RJF I've never seen a keyboard for a netbook that you could buy... probably due to the fact that netbooks are so cheap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I talked to eMachine support to see if I could buy a new keyboard.. This is what they said (Jordan Earls is me)

```
22 Apr 2010 10:53:39 AM Anil_GWSI1160 says: We do not sell the keypads for the netbooks. We dont recommend the customer to open the laptop, if he do so the warrenty will be void.
22 Apr 2010 10:54:22 AM Jordan Earls says: It may still be under warranty, but I am not sure. If it is, could it be sent to you guys to repair?
22 Apr 2010 10:54:24 AM Anil_GWSI1160 says: We will pull the computer for the repair. But this issue is not covered under warrenty as this issue seems to be liquid spill. We will charge $199 for the repair.
22 Apr 2010 10:54:44 AM Jordan Earls says: $199? That's almost the cost of a new netbook
22 Apr 2010 10:55:03 AM Anil_GWSI1160 says: I am sorry, its $99.
22 Apr 2010 10:55:11 AM Anil_GWSI1160 says: I apologize for the typo error.
22 Apr 2010 10:55:37 AM Jordan Earls says: oh. ok. Well, we will have to talk to the customer to see if that is what they would like us to do.
```

EDIT: Ok, we have now found this: http://www.laptopking.com/partpicture_LK.asp?ref=1658&category=keyboards  which is an almost exact same keyboard except for color and revision number. We are considering ordering it, but are pending customer approval.

Comment: Add new details by editing your question. Don't post an answer if it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Gno if no one else has anything good, then this will probably be the answer.

Comment: ok, in this case. I thought it was only adding details.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what was spilled on the keyboard I think you don't have a choice but to remove the keys (they are removable, just need to be careful not to break them off, you can find videos on youtube) because you'll need to clean the keys, the hinges and the rubber spring with some rubbing alcohol.

You could put the keys in a small bath of rubbing alcohol and clean the rest with a cotton swab dipped in rubbing alcohol

*edit*

Looking at pictures of that model it is possible to remove the keys without breaking them. However I do understand that it isn't your netbook and you don't want to risk breaking anything.

The next best thing would be to moisten a lint-free cloth with isopropyl alcohol or clean water (you obviously need to power off the netbook) and try to clean each key and if possible try to go under them (using a moist cotton swab). Other than that there isn't much you can do without popping the keys.

Comment: Easy to say but if we break a key on the keyboard and can't get a replacement keyboard, we basically have to buy them a new netbook

Comment: do you have the model of the netbook?

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: @Earlz, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whole keyboard and wash in de-ionized water.

Failing that, washing in warm water without detergents is probably OK too. Just make sure you dry thoroughly before reattaching.